# IIS does not accept %3C character (<)

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

A URL like this returns 404:

secure.domain.local:80/PaymentTransaction?ResponseXML=%3c%3fxml+version%3d

But I remove the `%3c` then it starts working. Of course, it then errors because the data is not being correctly sent.

NOTE: This is an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application.

Comment: What is your application technology? ASP.NET will generally throw a 500 at you for a "potentially dangerous request" for something like that, but not a 404. And I don't think IIS cares about that stuff, so I'd expect that to be in your application.

Comment: Good point @JoeEnos (it's ASP.NET MVC 4). However, I still think it's IIS because, if I recycle the application pool, the 404 is returned instantly and if I make a request to any other endpoint in the application it takes time to start the app.

Comment: This is funny: the controller action has the [ValidateInput(false)] attribute. I remember I used it before to prevent HTML input from breaking the app. It's really not getting there because there's some upper layer preventing it.

Comment: Any IIS extensions? Or URL Rewrite rules?

Comment: No, there's nothing like that on my IIS :S

Comment: Any updates yet? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry man, I don't even remember if that was fixed at all. That system is from a previous client and it is no longer in use. Feel free to post an answer after you get there so I can accept. Thanks